# Acessing other webapps while one is in document root

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, development-environment

I have a Zend Framework project on a local machine, and as recommended its /public subfolder is made a DocumentRoot in httpd.conf. So I access this app simply with http://localhost.

This new requirement makes me unable to access other
web apps in a former webserver root (which contains a few regular php apps and a couple of zend framework apps).

What configuration should I choose to be able to simultaneously access both ZF root-based apps and other apps like PHPMYADMIN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably need to use some kind of [`VirtualHost`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/)

You have at least two solutions :

- VirtualHosts based on diferent port numbers

  - For instance, you'd have one site on http://localhost/  (ie, default port = 80)
  - And another one on http://localhost:8001/
  - And another one on http://localhost:8802/
  - And so on
- VirtualHosts based on different domain-names

  - For instance, you'd have on site on http://localhost/
  - And another one on http://mytestwebsite/

In the second case (the solution I always use), you will have to edit your "`hosts`" file, so "mytestwebsite" is an alias to your local machine -- which IP address is 127.0.0.1

Under windows, this file is located in `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc`

On Linux, it's in `/etc/`

You'd have to add a line like these ones :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       mytestwebsite
```

Then, in the Apache configuration, you need to create one VirtualHost per site. Something like this, I suppose :

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName      mytestwebsite
    DocumentRoot /home/squale/developpement/tests
    <Directory /home/squale/developpement/tests>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName      myothertestwebsite
    DocumentRoot /.../myothertestwebsite
    <Directory /.../myothertestwebsite>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

(Needs tunning / configuration, of course)

And you'll also probably need some directive like this one :

```
NameVirtualHost *
```

Well, this might not be the **entire** solution (that one depends on your server / applications) ; but I hope these few pointers will help you get to it !

If you need more help, the keyword is "VirtualHost" **;-)**

Have fun !

Comment: That works and directive "NameVirtualHost *" was really useful to have two hosts at a time. Pascal, thanks for increasing my PHP productivity!

Comment: I'm having like 20 different projects like this. Works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework probably uses a .htaccess file. If so, you might use that to add rules to leave the other apps alone. Another option is to use subdomain (eg phpmyadmin.localhost)